# Convert base 10 number to a base 256 number on the JavaCard platform

Tags: java, arrays, javacard

I'd like to convert an ascii representation of a large number to a base 256 byte array representation.

More precise: To satisfy the following test.

The largest numerical type available on the JavaCard platform is short.

Restrictions: I do not have `javacardx.framework.math.BigNumber` available. I already have a way to add two byte arrays. `add(byte[], byte[])`.

```
@Test
public void convertAsciiNumber1234567890ToByteArray() {

    byte[] asciiAmount = new byte[]{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};

    byte[] result = ArrayUtil.convertAsciiAmount(asciiAmount, (short) 8);

    byte[] expected = new byte[]{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, (byte) 0x96, 0x02, (byte) 0xd2};
    assertEquals(expected[0], result[0]);
    assertEquals(expected[1], result[1]);
    assertEquals(expected[2], result[2]);
    assertEquals(expected[3], result[3]);
    assertEquals(expected[4], result[4]);
    assertEquals(expected[5], result[5]);
    assertEquals(expected[6], result[6]);
    assertEquals(expected[7], result[7]);
}
```

The second parameter for ArrayUtil.convertAsciiAmount is the length of the result array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is, once you've set the result to the first decimal digit, to then loop over the remaining digits, multiplying the result by 10 and adding the current digit.

The multiply and add routines use the standard "Big Integer" algorithms. Note that you need to save intermediate results in the next biggest integer representation, which in this case is short.

You could modify this code so that you didn't have to preallocate the result array, but instead grew it each time you needed.

```
public class DecToHex
{
    static int BASE = 0xFF;
    static int SHIFT = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte[] ascii = new byte[]{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
        byte[] result = convertAsciiAmount(ascii, (byte)8);
        printAsHex(result);
    }

    static byte[] convertAsciiAmount(byte[] ascii, byte capacity)
    {
        byte len = 0;
        byte[] result = new byte[capacity];

        result[0] = (byte)(ascii[0]-'0');
        for(byte i=1; i<ascii.length; i++)
        {
            byte digit = (byte)(ascii[i]-'0');

            // multiply result by 10
            len += 1;           
            short prod = 0;
            for(byte j=0; j<len; j++)
            {
                prod += (10 * (result[j]  & BASE));
                result[j] = (byte)prod;
                prod >>>= SHIFT;
            }
            result[len] = (byte)prod;           
            while(len > 0 && result[len-1] == 0) len--;

            // add current digit            
            short sum = 0;
            sum += (result[0] & BASE) + (digit & BASE);
            result[0] = (byte)sum;
            sum >>>= SHIFT;

            for(byte j=1; j<len; j++)
            {
                sum += (result[j] & BASE);
                result[j] = (byte)sum;
                sum >>>= SHIFT;
            }

            if(sum > 0)
            {
                result[len++] = (byte)sum;
            }
        }       
        return result;
    }

    static void printAsHex(byte[] hex)
    {
        for(byte i=(byte)(hex.length-1); i>=0; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(String.format("0x%02X", (hex[i] & BASE)) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();       
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x49 0x96 0x02 0xD2
```

Comment: Thank you! convertAsciiAmount() almost works, I just needed to reverse the result and replace int with short where necesary. I would accept your answer anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I find it much easier to think in little endian, but you wanted a big endian result. As you say, you can just reverse the result.